# How to remove root with children - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I can't remove root with all children...
This code is wrong but I can't not find a solution. [image: Database]

id - is a marked root which I want remove.

```
public void RemoveLeaf(int id)
{
    using (var context = new TreeDBtestEntities())
    {
        using(var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var root = context.DynamicTrees.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                int? idLeaf = root.Id;
                while (idLeaf != null)
                {
                    context.DynamicTrees.RemoveRange(context.DynamicTrees.Where(x => x.Id == id));

                    var result = context.DynamicTrees.Where(x => x.ParentId == idLeaf).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (result != null)
                        RemoveLeaf(result.Id);
                    idLeaf = null;

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want remove parent with all children. This code remove parent and only some children.

Can you help me?

Comment: What is wrong with the code? What is the expected and what the actual behavior?

Comment: I want remove parent with all children. This code remove parent and only some children.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can remove the recursion and handle this with just the `RemoveRange`

```
context.DynamicTrees.RemoveRange(context.DynamicTrees.Where(x => x.Id == id || x.ParentId == id));
context.SaveChanges();
```